/dev/dri not showing on Raspberry Pi5 Ubuntu 24.04 server headless
I'm trying to get access to the iGPU on the Pi5 running Ubuntu 24.04 server headless.
ls -l /dev/dri returns nothing.
Running lspci shows the iGPU is inaccessible
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM2712 PCIe Bridge (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: 00000000-005fffff [size=6M] [32-bit]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Raspberry Pi Ltd RP1 PCIe 2.0 South Bridge
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
        Memory at 1f00410000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 1f00000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4M]
        Memory at 1f00400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: rp1

I tried installing Ubuntu LTS Hardware Enablement Stack as recommended at No /dev/dri directory in Ubuntu Server 20.04 with no success. I got the error that a DTB was missing.
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-24.04ls -

Using DTB: bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-6.8.0-31-generic /lib/firmware/6.8.0-31-generic/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/6.8.0-31-generic/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb

I pulled bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb from Ubuntu's repo and placed it in /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs. Install worked. But after a reboot I still have no /dev/dri.
Any help would be appreciated.
